# Point of intersection of lines $\vec r \times \vec a=\vec b \times \vec a$ and $\vec r \times \vec b=\vec a \times \vec b$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

> > Let $\vec a= \hat i+\hat j$ and $\vec b =2 \hat i-\hat k$. Then the point of intersection of lines $\vec r \times \vec a=\vec b \times \vec a$ and $\vec r \times \vec b=\vec a \times \vec b$

**My Approach $1$:**

$\vec r \times \vec a =\vec b \times \vec a$

and $\vec r \times \vec b= -\vec b \times \vec a$

After Adding Above two  Equations I obtained

$\vec r \times (\vec a + \vec b)=\vec 0$

$\implies$
$\vec r =\lambda (\vec a +\vec b)$

**I am obtaining a line.**

**My Approach $2$:**

$\vec r \times \vec a = \vec b \times \vec a$

$\implies$ $(\vec r-\vec b) \times \vec a=\vec 0$

$\implies$ $\vec r = \vec b + \lambda \vec a ... (1)$

And

$\vec r \times \vec b = \vec a \times \vec b$

$\implies$ $(\vec r-\vec a) \times \vec b=\vec 0$

$\implies$ $\vec r = \vec a + \mu \vec b ... (2)$

From (1) and (2)

$\vec b + \lambda \vec a$ = $\vec a + \mu \vec b$

After comparing Two non colinear vector $\vec a$ and $\vec b$

I obtained $\lambda = \mu =1$

Which Give me $\vec r = \vec a+ \vec b$

Here I am getting a point only.

**Doubt:** Why Method $1$ is wrong?

I know i get same result for $\lambda =1$ but why cannot I take any other value of $\lambda$

**I know this Question is the same as [Point of intersection of the lines $\vec{r}\times\vec{a}=\vec{b}\times\vec{a}$ and $\vec{r}\times\vec{b}=\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367558/point-of-intersection-of-the-lines-vecr-times-veca-vecb-times-veca-a) but this does not solve my doubt. So please don't make it as duplicate.**

Answer (score 2):

You left method $1$ incomplete. Substituting $\vec r=\lambda (\vec a×\vec b)$ back to the original equations immediately gives $\lambda=1$, hence you get a point only.
The main problem with your approach is this:
$\vec r×\vec a=\vec b× \vec a$ and $\vec r×\vec b=\vec a×\vec b$ implies that $\vec r×(\vec a+\vec b)=0$, **but the converse is not true**. Hence it is necessary for you to check whether all values thus obtained satisfy the original equation.